# c# .net core api controller mixing route parameters and query parameters

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-web-api-routing

I have a url (that I can't really modify)  that has id as part of the route and then a start date and end date as query parameters.

I'm not sure how to mix route parameters and query parameters and bind them.

https://localhost:7285/api/roomEvents/1a?start=2022-10-30T00%3A00%3A00-04%3A00&end=2022-12-11T00%3A00%3A00-05%3A00

I'm struggling to bind the id, start, and end strings in my c# web api controller.

I've tried

```
 public class RoomEvents : BaseApiController
    {
        [AllowAnonymous]
        [HttpGet("{id}?start={start}&end={end}")]
        public async Task<ActionResult> GetRoomEvents(string id, string start, string end)
        {
           return HandleResult(await Mediator.Send(new EventsByRoom.Query { Id = id, Start = start, End = end }));
        }
         
    }
```

but I get

> System.ArgumentException   HResult=0x80070057   Message=The literal
> section '?start=' is invalid. Literal sections cannot contain the '?'
> character. (Parameter 'routeTemplate')
> Source=Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing

Comment: the parameters which have not been added to the route template will be available from the querystring. So, your route can be defined as `[HttpGet("{id}")]`. This can then be called with `/api/roomEvents/1a?start=...&end=...`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to change your `[HttpGet]` path and the method parameters to this

```cs
[HttpGet("{id}")]
public async Task<ActionResult> GetRoomEvents(
    string id,
    [FromQuery] string start,
    [FromQuery] string end)
    ...
```

The first parameter, `id` will be bound to the `{id}` portion of the path. for the latter two parameters you are explicitly telling ASP.NET that you want to bind to query parameters with the names `start` and `end` (using [[FromQuery]](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.fromqueryattribute?view=aspnetcore-7.0)).

You can also specify [[FromRoute]](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.fromrouteattribute?view=aspnetcore-7.0) for `id` if you want to be explicit, but that's the default.